# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.connToQuery" is null"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estoy tratando de soluciona el siguiente error al consultar mi base de datos.
Error

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.connToQuery" is null"
```

Ya comprobe y los variables si estan tienen valor guardado.

```
'private Connection connToQuery;

public DBConection(String userNameToLog, String userPassToLog) throws SQLException{
        
        try{
            
            String strConnToQuery ="SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE App_User_Name = '?' AND App_User_Password = '?';";
            PreparedStatement ps = connToQuery.prepareStatement(strConnToQuery);
            ps.setString(1, userNameToLog);
            ps.setString(2, userPassToLog);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            /*While to save the DB values. The numbers inside the getters arguments means the numbers of columns.
            The parameters also can be specified with the name of the columns.*/
            while(rs.next()){
               userIdToInfo = rs.getInt(1); 
               userFirstNameToInfo = rs.getString(2);
               userLastNameToInfo = rs.getString(3);
               userNameToInfo = rs.getString(4);
               passwordToInfo = rs.getString(5);
               userTypeToInfo = rs.getString(6);
            }
            userLoged = true;
        }
        
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }
    }'
```

Ahora de donde lo estoy llamando el objeto que me consulta la BD.

```
'
private void loginBTTN1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        
        char passArr[] = passwordLogTXTF.getPassword();
        String gettingLogUsername = usernameLogTXTF.getText(),
               
               recievingUserFirstName,
               recievingUserLastName;
        boolean isLoged;
        DBConection connectObjToLog,
                    accesingGetters;
        
        String gettingLogPassword = new String(passArr);
        
        try { 
            connectObjToLog = new DBConection(gettingLogUsername, gettingLogPassword);
            accesingGetters = new DBConection();
            isLoged = accesingGetters.getLogInStatus();
            
            if(isLoged == true){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome!" );
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(LogIn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
'
```

Comment: Tu variable connToQuery nunca fue inicializada, por ello obtienes el error por lo que esta pregunta es un duplicado de...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: @Ruslan Lopez gracias

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que la conexión no se ha inicializado, debes inicializarla usando [DriverManager.getConnection(...)](https://www.w3api.com/Java/DriverManager/getConnection/):

```
    Connection connToQuery = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

---

```
private Connection connToQuery;

public DBConection(String userNameToLog, String userPassToLog) throws SQLException{
        
        try{
            //* Define la conexión!
            Connection connToQuery = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            String strConnToQuery ="SELECT * FROM app_users WHERE App_User_Name = '?' AND App_User_Password = '?';";
            PreparedStatement ps = connToQuery.prepareStatement(strConnToQuery);
            ps.setString(1, userNameToLog);
            ps.setString(2, userPassToLog);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();
            
            /*While to save the DB values. The numbers inside the getters arguments means the numbers of columns.
            The parameters also can be specified with the name of the columns.*/
            while(rs.next()){
               userIdToInfo = rs.getInt(1); 
               userFirstNameToInfo = rs.getString(2);
               userLastNameToInfo = rs.getString(3);
               userNameToInfo = rs.getString(4);
               passwordToInfo = rs.getString(5);
               userTypeToInfo = rs.getString(6);
            }
            userLoged = true;
        }
        
        catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```